# How to build DataContractJsonSerialize convenience function

Tags: c#, json

I have a common code of serializing a class object  in my 3-4 methods ,So I am thinking to create a common function for that code and call function in all the methods

I am doingn this from the following code

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(this.GetType());
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ser.WriteObject(ms, this);

json = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());

ms.Close();
```

I want to put this common code in seprate general function which returns Json string and which accept whole class as input parameter as I am converting whole class into a Json object , I tried creating function like

public string GenerateJsonString(class C1)

but this is giving me error on the keyword "class" saying that type is required

Can anyone tell me how can I accept whole class object in seprate method or function

Comment: Six answers in less than 3 minutes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing a "class" with an "object".  You serialize an object, which is an instance of a particular class (aka "Type").

You can create a method taking a parameter of the .NET base type for all objects, "object", like this:

```
public static string GenerateJsonString(object o) 
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(o.GetType());
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ser.WriteObject(ms, o);
        json = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        ms.Close();
        return json;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Type the parameter as "object".  You can't pass a class as a parameter, only an instance of a class - which in OOP is referred to as an "object"

```
public string GenerateJsonString(object obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the objects that you are passing to this method are instances of classes that derive from a common base class, then you can use polymorphism and write the method to accept objects that are instances of the base class. Otherwise, all classes are derived from `System.Object`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "class object". If you mean an object, passing a reference to the object as normal does pass "the whole object" (well, a reference to it). You can get at all the members.

If you want to pass the *type* itself, you should declare the parameter as [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) - but I suspect that's not really what you want.

If you want to write a method which will accept any object, just declare the parameter as type [Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx):

```
public string GenerateJsonString(object x)
```

Personally I wouldn't use `Encoding.Default` (which is system-specific) to convert the binary to text, by the way - what encoding is the serializer really using? Does it let you pass in a TextWriter (e.g. a StringWriter) instead of a stream?

Answer (score 0):

You can accept an object.  A class is not instantiated and there for cannot be passed to the method.

Comment: One can instantiate a "Type" object referring to a class and pass that - but that's not related to this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Type instead of class

```
public string GenerateJsonString(Type t1)
```

Comment: If you get downvoted, have the guts to re-read the question and see if you really understood it. I gave a -1 for an incorrect answer and a misunderstanding of a problem.  It's nothing personal at all - don't take it as such.

Comment: I don't take it personal.  But in this case i answered the question as typed.  The questioner passed this.GetType(), not this.  Type is the logical type in that case not object.